# Parsing string, into multiple arrays, into dynamic dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have stored a dynamically created object as a string in a database because I lack knowledge of better choices and at this point I think there is no going back. I am trying to parse this is in a way so the user can not break it somehow.

I output a string that is in format

```
    |attr1|,subA,subB,subNth,~,|attrNth|,sub2A,sub2B,sub2C,sub2D,~
```

**1st**  then split it by doing

```
    supertest = option.split("~");
```

Leaving me with

```
    |attr1|,subA,subB,subNth,,,|attrNth|,sub2A,sub2B,sub2C,sub2D,,
```

**2nd** I loop through find my pipe symbols, and split again

```
   for(n=0; n<supertest.length; n++) {

        var start_pos = supertest[n].indexOf('|') + 1;
        var end_pos = supertest[n].indexOf('|',start_pos);
        var optionParsed = supertest[n].substring(start_pos,end_pos);
        test = supertest[n].split("|").pop();

        choiceArray = test.split(",");
        }
```

Leaving me with 3 arrays with dynamically created names(I only want two)

```
 array1- ,subA,subB,subNth,
 array2- ,sub2A,sub2B,sub2C,sub2D,
 array3- blank or null or undefined?
```

**JSFIDDLE:**  http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/4YHSr/21/

I am ultimately trying to create dynamic select input lists with "attr"'s as labels and "subNths" as options. so I tried to create a jsfiddle to make it easier, because i now realize this is a bigger question than i initially thought, but for some reason after the three select drop down lists are done loading everything disappears. I tried. If anyone can 
help me I would appreciate it. What I ideally want to know is how can i get my individual arrays to be in the format

```
attr1 = [subA, subB, subNth]
```

Thank you for anyone who thinks they might know this and can help

Comment: I realise it may be too late, but had you not considered storing the objects as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)?

Comment: It's never too late, rebuild time !

Comment: @DavidThomas ha yeah I am learning as I go and that sounds like a great idea based on the three like button click you got already. Would storing it as JSON mean storing in a MySQL table or maybe local storage? as an object? Am i really that bad off? cause that is going to be digging deep...

Comment: Effectively using JSON would turn a JavaScript object into a string-representation of the object, for example (forgive the illegibility of the code in comments): `var xkcd = { author: 'Randall Munroe', urls: ['http://xkcd.com', 'http://m.xkcd.com'], updated: ['Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday'] }, xkcdToJSON = JSON.stringify(xkcd); console.log(xkcdToJSON);` more-legible [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sZBcC/1/) (outputs: `'{"author":"Randall Munroe","urls":["http://xkcd.com","http://m.xkcd.com"],"updated":["Monday","Wednesday","Friday"]}'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we choose to overlook the fact that you indeed need to refactor your code and implement a more robust, reliable and maintanable solution for storing such data (JSON sounds like a good choice), your main problem is this:

- You have a callback on your submit button, which means that, right after your callback is executed and the `select`s created, your form gets submitted (to nowhere in this case) and your page is reloaded (effectively causing your changes to get lost).

All you have to do is add `return false;` at the end of your submit callback, which will prevent the form from getting submitted.

You might also want to add a couple of checks to omit `option`s (or `select`s) when the corresponding token is empty. Something like this would do:

```
for (var n = 0; n < supertest.length; n++) {
    if (supertest[n] == "") { continue; }
    ...
    for (var j = 0; j < choiceArray.length; j++) {
        if (choiceArray[j] == "") { continue; }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
return false;
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fbYwc/)**.

Comment: oye that looks good, I am used to overlooking my mistakes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope, the working code below can convince you to use JSON for storing hierarchical data ;)
And yes, its only the parsing part.

```
var zzz = '|attr1|,subA,subB,subNth,~,|attrNth|,sub2A,sub2B,sub2C,sub2D,~'
   .split('~')
   .filter(function(v){return !!v;})
   .map(function(v) {
       var a = v.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/, '')
          .split(',');
       var o = {};
       o[a[0].replace(/\|/g, '')] = a.slice(1);
       return o;
   }); 

// now, lets see what we have done:
JSON.stringify(zzz); 
// and the output is:
"[{"attr1":["subA","subB","subNth"]},{"attrNth":["sub2A","sub2B","sub2C","sub2D",""]}]"
```